# Как правильно впихнуть данные в json?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Всем привет. Помогите построить структуру json запроса.

Я уже запарился всякие вариации делать, первый раз над этим сижу, поэтому прошу помощи.

Есть форма, с формы делаю выборку с помощью `serializeArray()`. Тут всё окей, структура строится верная. Дальше мне надо помимо данных с формы, отправить другие данные, которые будут иметь вид:

```
var myObj = {
    "flavors": [
        {"id":"id", "value": "value"},
        {"id":"id", "value": "value"}
    ],
}
```

Как мне правильно теперь "скрестить" данные с формы и другие данные (`flavor[]`)? Как делается обычно? Может я просто зациклился на чём-то непонятном, а всё намного проще делается!?
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Не совсем выходит так как надо, не знаю как лучше объединить данные так, что бы на сервере было бы проще работать со всеми данными..
пробовал так...

```
var myObj = {
            "flavors": [
                {"id":"id", "value": "value"},
                {"id":"id", "value": "value"}
            ],
            "form": [

            ]
        };

 var inputs_data = $(this).serializeArray();
        myObj.form.push(inputs_data);
```

### На выходе получается так:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: всё зависит от того, в каком виде от вас ждёт эти данные сервер, но лучше не смешивать молоко и огурцы, а отправить 2 массива объектов, лежащих рядом. Например: `var myObj = {
    "flavors": [], "form": [] };`

Comment: Понял, а как можно var inputs_data = $(this).serializeArray(); запихнуть в myObj ?

Comment: пробовал так, смотрите отредактированный вопрос

Comment: `myObj.form = inputs_data`

Comment: Понял. Объясните тогда пожалуйста, почему когда я отправляю только inpust_data, то получаю ответ в таком виде http://prntscr.com/dt2x4a
А когда объединяю то http://prntscr.com/dt2xxm . На сервере не очень удобно будет работать с таким видом..

Comment: это не из-за объединения, это из-за `serializeArray()`

Comment: Я понимаю, поэтому такой и вопрос как собрать всё в нормальный вид, что бы проще можно было бы работать на сервере..

Comment: я написал к тому, что если убрать serializeArray(), то по идее будет такой объект как был раньше :) и не нужно будет его делать

Answer (score 1):

Решил свой вопрос так:

```
  var myObj = {
        "flavors": [
            {"id":"id", "value": "value"},
            {"id":"id", "value": "value"}
        ],
        "form": [

        ]
    };

 var inputs = {};
        $.each($(this).serializeArray(), function(i, field) {
           inputs[field.name] = field.value;
        });
 myObj.form = inputs;
```

Получаю данные такого вида:

```
  array:2 [▼
  "flavors" => array:2 [▼
    0 => array:2 [▼
      "id" => "id"
      "value" => "value"
    ]
    1 => array:2 [▶]
  ]
  "form" => array:8 [▼
    "name" => ""
    "descr" => ""
    "image" => ""
    "_token" => "O2tQBPsByYbfjvcMxghp4uHxodRNHFdPbvXx6kw9"
    "volume" => "3"
    "nic" => "3"
    "pg_value" => "50"
    "premium" => "on"
  ]
]
```